# React Next.js - Multiple Layout yarn build fail

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

At first i restructure layout and page following this [Next.JS: Multiple layouts patterns with typescript](https://alexjohnsuarez.medium.com/next-js-multiple-layouts-patterns-with-typescript-b3b8385a8c4)

when running site at local it work fine with no error.But when build with yarn predeploy(npm run clean && next build) this error is happen.

```
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/7)Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bchildren%7D for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:490)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)

Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bchildren%7D for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:490)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:74:209)
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
    at Z (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
info  - Generating static pages (7/7)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /_error: /500
    at /Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:395:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1094:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:971:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:64:29)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

what is a problem?

**additionnal info**

**_app.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactElement} from "react";
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-tailwind/react";
import PageWithLayoutType from "../pageWithLayouts";
import "@/styles/globals.css";

type AppLayoutProps = AppProps & {
  Component: PageWithLayoutType;
  pageProps: any;
};

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppLayoutProps) {
  const Layout =
    Component.layout || ((children: ReactElement) => <>{children}</>);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**pageWithLayouts.tsx**

```
import { NextPage } from "next"
import { ReactElement } from "react"
import MainLayout from "@/src/components/layoutIndex"
import PortfolioLayout from "@/src/components/layoutPortfolio"
import AdminLayout from "@/src/components/layoutAdmin"
import BlogLayout from "@/src/components/layoutBlog"
import WorkLayout from "@/src/components/layoutWork"

export type PageWithMainLayoutType = NextPage & { layout: typeof MainLayout }
export type PageWithPortfolioLayoutType = NextPage & { layout: typeof PortfolioLayout }
export type PageWithBlogLayoutType = NextPage & { layout: typeof BlogLayout }
export type PageWithWorkLayoutType = NextPage & { layout: typeof WorkLayout }
export type PageWithAdminLayoutType = NextPage & { layout: typeof AdminLayout }

export type PageWithLayoutType =
 | PageWithMainLayoutType
 | PageWithPortfolioLayoutType 
 | PageWithBlogLayoutType 
 | PageWithWorkLayoutType 
 | PageWithAdminLayoutType

export type LayoutProps = ({
 children,
}: {
 children: ReactElement
}) => ReactElement
export default PageWithLayoutType
```

**work.tsx**

```
import WorkLayout from "../components/layoutWork";

type Props = {};

const Work = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Work</div>
    </>
  );
};
Work.layout = WorkLayout;
export default Work;
```

**layoutWork.tsx**

```
import type { LayoutProps } from "../pageWithLayouts"
const WorkLayout: LayoutProps = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
export default WorkLayout
```

**Current progress ========**

i try change tsconfig.json => "strict": false.
now whenever i run (build or dev). it's show this error.

```
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
info  - Linting and checking validity of types .Failed to compile.

./src/pages/_app.tsx:27:6
Type error: Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>': type, props, key

  25 | return (
  26 |   <ThemeProvider>
> 27 |     <Layout>
     |      ^
  28 |       <Component {...pageProps} />
  29 |     </Layout>
  30 |     </ThemeProvider>

> Build error occurred
Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:11661)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/Users/blackjack/Documents/Dev Personal/portnext/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12599)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  type: 'WorkerError'
}
```

I think it missing some "props" or propertie that come with it.
But i don't know typescipt well enough to fix this.
Any help or even keyword is Greatly appreciated.